# CocoaLibSpotify: Unrecognized selector on Login and Search

Tags: ios, spotify

I'm having a pretty consistent issue here, and have literally searched everywhere to no avail. I've been having a ton of problems with CocoaLibSpotify, and this error is just more hours being wasted of my employer, but anyways.

Whenever I attempt to login or do an SPSearch I get an unrecognized selector and the application crashes. Here's the code below. Thanks for your patience!

```
 SPDispatchAsync(^{
NSError *error = nil;

//[SPSession class];
[SPSession initializeSharedSessionWithApplicationKey:[NSData dataWithBytes:&g_appkey length:g_appkey_size]
                                           userAgent:@"com.mattie.montgomery.listenin"
                                       loadingPolicy:SPAsyncLoadingManual
                                               error:&error];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"CocoaLibSpotify init failed: %@", error);
    abort();
}


[[SPSession sharedSession] setDelegate:self];


[[SPSession sharedSession] attemptLoginWithUserName:@"USERNAME" password:@"PASSWORD"];

    // playbackManager = [[SPPlaybackManager alloc] initWithPlaybackSession:[SPSession     sharedSession]];


   //[search addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"searchInProgress" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
   //  search = [SPSearch searchWithSearchQuery:@"What is love" inSession:[SPSession sharedSession]];
```

});

Here's the exception:

2014-01-13 13:24:48.890 ListenIn[47201:4303] +[NSError spotifyErrorWithCode:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2cd8298
2014-01-13 13:24:48.979 ListenIn[47201:4303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSError spotifyErrorWithCode:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2cd8298'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x030835e4 **exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02e068b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x031207a3 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0307390b __*forwarding*** + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x030734ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   ListenIn                            0x00039a6b logged_in + 139
    6   ListenIn                            0x0018c1de sp_session_set_private_session + 538
    7   ListenIn                            0x000f0cf7 -[SPClientUpsellViewController .cxx_destruct] + 639639
    8   ListenIn                            0x0009c277 -[SPClientUpsellViewController .cxx_destruct] + 292887
    9   ListenIn                            0x0018af5f sp_session_process_events + 80
    10  ListenIn                            0x0003854c -[SPSession prodSessionForcefully] + 332
    11  ListenIn                            0x0003cf2c **notify_main_thread_block_invoke + 44
    12  ListenIn                            0x0002b63d __54+[SPSession dispatchToLibSpotifyThread:waitUntilDone:]_block_invoke + 93
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x030421c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 16
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0300b3f9 **CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 361
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x03029843 __CFRunLoopRun + 2355
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x03028ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x03033e61 CFRunLoopRun + 129
    18  ListenIn                            0x0002b905 +[SPSession runBackgroundRunloop:] + 437
    19  Foundation                          0x02a5e597 -[NSThread main] + 76
    20  Foundation                          0x02a5e4f6 _*NSThread*_main** + 1275
    21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x05dc15fb _pthread_body + 144
    22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x05dc1485 _pthread_struct_init + 0
    23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x05dc6cf2 thread_start + 34
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Anyone? I've been working at this for three hours today.

Comment: Don't put your username and password on the internet!!

Comment: Woops! Completely forgot that was there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to add the -ObjC linker flag and add the Facebook API to the project. Thanks to iKenndac for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't put account credentials like your username and password on the public internet.

As for your problem, pasting in a big block of code isn't very helpful - which line actually generates the error?

Your commented out code at the bottom is in the wrong order - you can't add an observer to something until after you've created it.

Finally, please re-read the readme, specifically the part about threading. You only need to use `SPDispatchAsync` in very specific circumstances, and you should never be using it in normal usage like this.

Comment: I'm getting the error on login and search. It with or without SPDispatch.

Comment: Updated the main post with exception info

Comment: Please re-read the "Building - iOS" section of the readme carefully. It appears you've missed a required linker flag (-ObjC).

Comment: When the -ObjC flag is added I get a number of linker errors. I was advised to remove it in a previous question.